# Django - Error selecting objects: "ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer)

Tags: python, django

My models.py contains

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    cpf_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    name_txt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nr_record = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

The database is postgresql.

When I try to select an object with

```
>>> Patient.objects.get(nr_record=1)
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151,     in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
.
.
.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in     execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...d" FROM "quiz_patient" WHERE "quiz_patient"."nr_record" = 1 
                                                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add     explicit type casts.
```

I'm newbie in Django-python. But until I know models.Autofield is integer type.

Searched web, but despite posts with same error message, didn't find nothing like my problem.

Comment: Just curious--any reason you're using the AutoField? Django automatically creates a `pk` field that does this for you. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). Not saying you can't use AutoField, just saying it might already be done for you.

Comment: The desiners of database have chosen another name. Just that. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. Works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most certainly with your database. Maybe you had a previous version of the model where nr_record was not an integer?

Try removing the nr_record column in the database and adding it again.

Comment: Yes, great! I've deleted the database and created a new one from scratch. Syncing database again now it's working. Thank you!